# How can I use the Wazuh 4.3 API or interface to retrieve log information from the /var/ossec/logs/alerts directory?

Tags: wazuh

How can I use the Wazuh 4.3 API or interface to retrieve log information from the /var/ossec/logs/alerts directory?After reviewing the official documentation, I found that calling https://192.168.186.134:55000/manager/logs did not retrieve the information I was looking for.

I tried using the official document[wiki](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/api/reference.html#operation/api.controllers.manager_controller.get_log), but it didn't give me what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

To get the vulnerabilities of an agent, you can review the following [documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/api/reference.html#operation/api.controllers.vulnerability_controller.get_vulnerability_agent).

```
{protocol}://{host}:{port}/vulnerability/{agent_id}

{
"data": {
"affected_items": [],
"total_affected_items": 2,
"total_failed_items": 0,
"failed_items": [ ]
},
"message": "All selected vulnerabilities were returned",
"error": 0
}
```

Let me know if my help helped you.

Greetings

Nicolas

Comment: Sorry for not replying to you in a timely manner. Thank you very much for your answer. I found the answer I wanted. Thank you very much。

Answer (score 0):

The Wazuh API does not have an endpoint to do this since alerts are directly indexed into Elasticsearch.

Use the Elasticsearch API.
Asked and answered here: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/discussions/20485